# Liftability in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p

What clsses of algebraic varieties over field of positive characteristic can be lift to $W_2(k)$?

Comment: Curves, K3 surfaces, abelian varieties, ... is there more context to the question or is this just a "big list"?

Comment: All affine varieties, trivially! 
are you assuming $k$ to be perfect? and is the motivation stemming from Deligne-Illusie's famous paper?

Comment: In addition to affine varieties, curves, K3 surfaces, abelian varieties, have anything else which statisfy the liftability? The $k$ may be perfect or even algebraically closed.

Comment: Is there a particular variety or class of varieties you want to be liftable?  Perhaps that would give you a better answer.

Comment: I want to know as much as possible class of schemes or varieties(especially projective)， which can be lift to $W_2(k)$. Does any toric varieties always liftable?

Comment: Here's something really interesting. The examples I listed I knew lifted to $W_2$ because I knew they lifted to characteristic $0$ and then went backwards. But what is something that lifts to $W_2$ but not $W_3$, or what is something that lifts all the way up to get a formal scheme over $Spf(W)$ but then doesn't algebraize to give a lift to characteristic $0$. Of course, this isn't my question to change it ...

Comment: @Universe, I think I remember seeing a paper of Qihong Xie on what you can lift to $W_2(k)$ for toric varieties.  But my recollection is that the answer is basically *everything.*

Comment: I couldn't find a reference - but don't all Frobenius split varieties lift to $W_2$?

Comment: @hilbertthm90 - you might find this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45089/non-algebraizable-formal-scheme relevant